# In ReactJS, how can I assign multiple ref to a single DOM?

Tags: reactjs, react-ref

I have a dialogue component in which I have created a ref, but I also want to pass the ref from the parent to it. How can I do this?

```
import { forwardRef } from "react";

export const PopOver = ({
  show = false,
  ...
}, ref) => {

  const thisRef = useRef(null);

  // dealing with UI changes with 'thisRef'

  return (
    <div
      ref={thisRef}, // How can I add a `ref` here?
      ....
    >
      Hello world
    </div>
  );
};

export default forwardRef(PopOver);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap it with another element and pass parent ref to it
sth like this :

```
   <div ref={ref}>
    <div
      ref={thisRef}
      ....
    >
      Hello world
    </div>
  </div>
```

or if you want to replace ref you can do it in useEffect
like this :

```
useEffect(()=>{
 if(ref.current){
  thisRef.current = ref.current
   }
},[ref])
```

Comment: Thank you for responding. However, adding a dummy <div> just for reference will complicate the DOM tree.

Comment: However, there is no other way to create another ref same DOM element.

Comment: that's right, I've tried it before and the same as you, I couldn't find any better solution